# an instruction inside Public void done of Parse is Local, android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm having an issue with a String variable in Android and I'm not able to make the String variable global.

Here is my code :

```
 String nom;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mescontacts);
     ParseQuery<ParseObject> query2 = ParseQuery.getQuery("test"); 
                     query2.whereEqualTo("phone", "0624982192");
                     query2.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() 

                     {

                       public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) 
                       {

                         if(e == null)
                         {

                        nom = "hhhhh";



                         }
                          Toast.makeText(Mescontacts.this, "nom : "+nom, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

the value of the string variable "nom" is null when i'm showing it on screen, but if i show the variable inside the done function it works.

So please how can i show the variable outside of the done function ?

Comment: What exactly you need to display instead of null?

Comment: well it should show "hhhhh"

Comment: That is the code that actually is working? I mean that Toast is showing "hhhh"?

Comment: Your nom gets initialized only when you call done method and hence you see it as null. So i would suggest, you define nom as hhhh initially and then change accordingly.

Comment: @Alvaro Perez Soria no the Toast is showing "null" I want it to Show "hhhh" #almasshaikh the done function is called automatically if you really worked with Parse.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As getFirstInBackground is an async call, when you call it, program continues, so that is why your variable is not initialized until end is called. You should consider including the code to show the string on the screen inside done callback.

Comment: I know that ! but I need a way on how I can do that without showing it inside the function done